# Firebase storage document preview in browser with rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I locked down my storage rules so that only authenticated users with specific roles can write/read documents. Ok, that works (write and read rules are the same). But when I open the download url in a new tab to preview the document, I get unauthorized.

Is this just not possible for secured documents? Am I going to have to just straight up download the file and make the user open it locally?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the code you're using that doesn't work the way you expect?  Download URLs should be publicly available to anyone who has the URL.

Comment: I was trying to use the FilePath as the download URL :)
When I used the document reference to get the download url, I was able to open it fine.